# How do you access English recruiters and jobs in a location that is not primarily English speaking?

Tags: job-search, international, asia, china, language

I'm currently residing in Hong Kong.  I know there are English speakers everywhere, and there are employment locations that are purely English speaking, and I know English-only employees exists because I know them.

I have no idea how to find these jobs.  I'm Chinese, born in Hong Kong, but moved to Canada for 25 years.  I'm conversational in Cantonese, but would much prefer an English work environment.

However, most of the recruiters I have found are primarily Cantonese speakers (the local language).  I have no idea how to access the English recruiters.

The friends I know are hired overseas and transferred, but I presume they have other staff with them that are local.

What are some strategies to access employment resources in English?

Update:  I'm a Web Developer, and I'm looking for positions that uses the new MEAN stack or its derivatives.

Comment: So are you still on canada looking for english jobs? Or are you back in hong kong? It would help if you clarify that or add a relevant tag to your question

Comment: I did... It's the first sentence... I'm currently residing in Hong Kong.

Comment: Sorry, missed that detail. Added a relevant tag to your question, feel free to further edit it.

Comment: I would just use the same recruiters expats use or use English job boards with listings in HK. Why post on an English job board if you don't want English speakers, am I right?

Comment: I think it would help if you told us in what profession you are seeking - the answers may vary depending on that.

Comment: Are you just looking for jobs where the main language will be English or do you also want to find recruiters that primarily speak English? Any recruiter should be able to look through their portfolio to find jobs where English is the main language, but if you only want English speaking recruiters too, you may have a more difficult time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for Canadian and US companies that have a office in Honkong - for those your cultural background alone could be a hiring reason. 
This depends a little bit on the Field you are looking for - works well for office-jobs.

You can also just look for normal jobs on the sites that are typically used there, filter the jobs that require excellent English and then just send your application in English and state in the cover letter that you are seeking for an English-speaking workplace.

Answer (score 2):

Search engines can help you.

Google has tools to help you do this. I don't think Google is blocked in Hong Kong, but if it is you can always use a Chinese search engine like Baidu to similar effect.

Google offers an option to display only results from Hong Kong (enter search terms, hit enter, tools menu, country selection). If you have a Google account you can also specify which languages you want results in, so limit it to English.

Then search for English terms like "jobs" and "english speaking". When I tried this I saw several sites such as www.indeed.hk and jobsinhongkong.com that are dedicated to English speaking users, and have options to filter by jobs that accept English-only applicants.

Similarly, you can search for phrases like "location hong kong". Combined with "careers" or "recruitment" that seems to turn up a few employers with offices there.